# Condition_variable wait_for timeout issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to learn how to get conditional variables working with some threads, but am having some troubles. The goal is to get the main thread to spawn some 'tasks' for a set period of time which instantiates a Countdown object that includes a thread which uses the timeout of the condition_variable to know that the requested time has indeed lapsed before notifying the caller.

Each time I run the example below it gets a different result, sometimes erroring out, sometimes running, but the timeout for both child threads is shorter than requested (assuming it gets that far).

I appreciate that there are other ways to skin-the-cat to time threads and I could for instance use atomic_x or other means instead of a callback, but I just would like to see how to get the spirit of this implementation (i.e. conditional variable so I don't have to poll).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using Time = std::chrono::system_clock;
using Seconds = std::chrono::seconds;
using Timepoint = Time::time_point;

class Countdown {
private:
    Timepoint               target;
    std::thread             t;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex              cv_m;
    unsigned int            guid;
    std::string             name;

public:
    Countdown() 
    { // Needed to compile, but doesn't appear to run 
        std::cout << "empty Countdown constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Countdown(unsigned int guid_, std::string name_, unsigned int waitFor, std::function<void(unsigned int)> callback)
        : guid(guid_)
        , name(name_)
        , target(Time::now() + Seconds(waitFor))
    {

        auto exec_run = [this, guid_, waitFor, callback]() mutable {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            std::cout << "[Thread " << guid_ << "] waiting for " << waitFor << " seconds." << std::endl;
 
            Timepoint before = Time::now();
            if (cv.wait_until(lk, target) == std::cv_status::timeout)
            {
                Timepoint after = Time::now();
                std::chrono::duration<float> difference = after - before;
                std::cout << "[Thread " << guid_ << "] Elapsed " << difference.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
                callback(guid_);
            } 
        };
        
        t = std::thread(exec_run);
    }

    Countdown(Countdown &&from) // move constructor
    {
        //std::cout << "Countdown move constructor" << std::endl; 
        target = from.target;
        t = std::move(from.t);
        name = from.name;
        guid = from.guid;
    }

    ~Countdown()
    {
        //std::cout << "~Countdown()" << std::endl; 
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }
};

class Holder {
private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Countdown>   waitlist;
    unsigned int                        id;
    std::vector<unsigned int>           completed;

public:
    Holder()
        : id(0)
    { }

    // Create a new task with a name for WaitFor (s) period of time
    unsigned int addTask(std::string name, unsigned int waitFor) {
        id++;
        waitlist.emplace(std::pair(id, Countdown(id, name, waitFor, 
                                  std::bind(&Holder::taskComplete, this, std::placeholders::_1))));

        return id;
    }

    void taskComplete(unsigned int id)
    {
        std::cout << "[Thread " << id << "] taskComplete" << std::endl;
        // Add task id to the completed list to be picked up by main thread
        completed.push_back(id);
    }

    void cleanupCompleted()
    {
        // Purge the completed entries from the waitlist
        for (auto& id : completed)
        {
            std::cout << "[Main] Erasing task: " << id << std::endl;
            waitlist.erase(id);
        }

        // Empty the completed list
        completed.clear();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Holder *h = new Holder();
    // Create a task which spawns a thread, which notifies us when complete
    unsigned int id1 = h->addTask("fluffy", 1); // 1 second task
    unsigned int id2 = h->addTask("woof", 4);   // 4 second task
    std::cout << "[Main]: Done adding tasks.." << std::endl;
 
    // Rest a while..
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(Seconds(5));
    h->cleanupCompleted();

    // Just to show the main thread continues on.
    std::cout << "[Main]: Doing other stuff.." << std::endl;
    delete(h);

    return 0;
}
```

**Actual / Expected Result:**

```
[Main]: Done adding tasks..
[Thread 2] waiting for 4 seconds.
[Thread 1] waiting for 1 seconds.
[Thread 2] Elapsed 8.243e-06 seconds. **(This should be ~ 4 seconds)**
[Thread 2] taskComplete
[Thread 1] Elapsed 0.000124505 seconds. **(This should be ~1 second)**
[Thread 1] taskComplete
[Main] Erasing task: 2
[Main] Erasing task: 1
[Main]: Doing other stuff..
```

I 'think' the problem might be around the in-place addition of the 'Countdown' object to the  map in the 'Holder' class. It needs a move constructor whereby I manually set each field (except the mutex and conditional_variable).

Any advice on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Are you using `g++` or `clang++`? If you are, [use the power of the Sanitizers](https://godbolt.org/z/Mrachj3Gv). Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run your program, fix all the issues. Then compile with `-g -fsanitize=thread` and run your program, fix all the issues. Go back to using `address,undefined` and repeat until none of those sanitizers report any errors. Unfortunately, you can't combine the `thread`sanitizer with `address,undefined` so you'll have to compile them separately.

Comment: Hey Ted. Funny you should respond. I'm investigating this based on your suggestion from yesterday. I'm using g++. I will give your advice a try =).

Comment: It's a small world :-) Hope you find the sanitizers as useful as I do!

Comment: Apparently all-the-action is in the fsanitize=thread. Now my next rabbit hole to understand and fix it =)

Comment: Yeah, the thread sanitizer's output isn't as easy to understand as the address,undefined output imo, but as you can see in the link, asan & ubsan also reports _"stack-use-after-return"_ so you could start with trying to understand that one. When compiled with `-Wall -Wextra` the compiler also reports _"...will be initialized after"_ which isn't a problem here, but it's a sign of that you're trying to initialize things in the wrong order. Try to get it free from those kinds of compiler warnings too.

Comment: After reading you question a couple of times I'm still having hard time understanding the final goal. Are you trying to schedule a number of tasks so they all executed in (an arbitrary?) order or you want them all to start simultaneously and get callback when all of them are finished?

Comment: For the bigger use case, tasks would arrive arbitrarily, so I wanted a way to manage a list of open tasks and the threads that are executing them. In a previous iteration, I was polling to see if an atomic was changed and I wanted something better than polling to know if a task was completed. The wait_until of a condition_variable gave me the chance to run different tasks of mocked up length using the timeout as proxy for different workloads instead of a predicate. In short a contrived example to learn more about newer parts of the language I less familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I have it, so I'll post the solution below. It came down to a number of mistakes on my part;

- from compile switches **-g -fsanitize=thread** I was able to see I had a number of read/write race conditions and a bunch of other excitement which required some love from a bunch of mutexes.
- following from above I was calling a read from the thread after the parent object was destroyed. This was because the construction of Coundown object and it's insertion into the waitlist map, caused a move constructor to be created twice, so I separated out another function (start) which would then start the thread after all the constructor nonsense was finished with.
- From compile switch **-Wall** picked up I was initializing the initialization list out of order (I didn't know that was a thing)

.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using Time = std::chrono::system_clock;
using Seconds = std::chrono::seconds;
using Timepoint = Time::time_point;

class Countdown {
private:
    Timepoint               target;
    unsigned int            guid;
    std::string             name;
    std::thread             t;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex              cv_m;

public:
    Countdown() // Needed to compile, but doesn't appear to run 
    { }

    Countdown(unsigned int guid_, std::string name_, unsigned int waitFor)
        : target(Time::now() + Seconds(waitFor))
        , guid(guid_)
        , name(name_)
    { }

    Countdown(Countdown &&from) // move constructor
    {
        //std::cout << "Countdown move constructor" << std::endl; 
        target = from.target;
        t = std::move(from.t);
        name = from.name;
        guid = from.guid;
    }

    ~Countdown()
    {
        //std::cout << "~Countdown()" << std::endl; 
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }

    void start(std::function<void(unsigned int)> callback)
    {
        auto exec_run = [this, callback]() mutable {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            unsigned int guid = getGUID();
            //std::time_t target = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(getTarget());
            //std::cout << "[Thread " << guid << "] waiting for " << std::ctime(&target) << " seconds." << std::endl;
 
            Timepoint before = Time::now();
            if (cv.wait_until(lk, target) == std::cv_status::timeout)
            {
                Timepoint after = Time::now();
                std::chrono::duration<float> difference = after - before;
                std::cout << "[Thread " << guid << "] Elapsed " << difference.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
                callback(guid);
            } 
        };
        
        t = std::thread(exec_run);
    }

    unsigned int getGUID() { return guid; }

};

class Holder {
private:
    unsigned int                        id;
    std::map<unsigned int, Countdown>   waitlist;
    std::mutex                          waitlist_mutex;
    std::vector<unsigned int>           completed;
    std::mutex                          completed_mutex;

public:
    Holder()
        : id(0)
    { }

    // Create a new task with a name for WaitFor (s) period of time
    unsigned int addTask(std::string name, unsigned int waitFor) {
        id++;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(waitlist_mutex);
        Countdown newCountdown(id, name, waitFor);
        
        // Needed to separate the following into 3 lines to give the move constructors a chance
        // to settle down, and separate out a start which initiates the thread so that the thread
        // isn't trying to access stuff as the destructors after the move constructor are called
        std::pair<unsigned int, Countdown> pair(id, std::move(newCountdown));
        waitlist.emplace(std::move(pair));
        
        waitlist[id].start(std::bind(&Holder::taskComplete, this, std::placeholders::_1)); 
        
        return id;
    }

    void taskComplete(unsigned int id)
    {
        std::cout << "[Thread " << id << "] taskComplete" << std::endl;
        // Add task id to the completed list to be picked up by main thread
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(completed_mutex);
        completed.push_back(id);
    }

    void cleanupCompleted()
    {
        // Purge the completed entries from the waitlist
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard_c(completed_mutex);

        for (auto& id : completed)
        {
            std::cout << "[Main] Erasing task: " << id << std::endl;
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard_w(waitlist_mutex);
            waitlist.erase(id);
        }

        // Empty the completed list
        completed.clear();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Holder *h = new Holder();
    // Create a task which spawns a thread, which notifies us when complete
    h->addTask("fluffy", 1);
    h->addTask("woof", 4);
    std::cout << "[Main]: Done adding tasks.." << std::endl;
 
    // Rest a while..
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(Seconds(5));
    h->cleanupCompleted();

    // Just to show the main thread continues on.
    std::cout << "[Main]: Doing other stuff.." << std::endl;
    delete(h);

    return 0;
}
```

...and the proof =)

```
[Main]: Done adding tasks..
[Thread 1] Elapsed 0.999498 seconds.
[Thread 1] taskComplete
[Thread 2] Elapsed 3.99984 seconds.
[Thread 2] taskComplete
[Main] Erasing task: 1
[Main] Erasing task: 2
[Main]: Doing other stuff..
```

Thanks again Ted =)

Comment: Cool! Next, compile your program normally (without sanitizers) and use `valgrind --tool=helgrind --exit-on-first-error=yes --error-exitcode=1 ./your_program` which is a thread error detector that's also pretty good, but I'm not sure _how_ good. It _does_ report a _possible_ data race that might be worth looking in to.